# Error 415: Unsupported Media Type - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using the code of [this Kotlin tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) to upload files to my ASP.NET MVC Core API.
That code is compiling and seems to be working. But I can't figure out on how to receive it on my API.

This is the code I am using to receive the file:

```
public interface IFormFile
{
    string ContentType { get; }
    string ContentDisposition { get; }
    IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
    long Length { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string FileName { get; }
    Stream OpenReadStream();
    void CopyTo(Stream target);
    Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

[HttpPost("upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile formFile)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TEST");
        
        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName(); //we are using Temp file name just for the example. Add your own file path.
        //filePaths.Add(filePath);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.
    return Ok();
}
```

When sending a file, I get the following error response:

```
I/System.out: FILE RESP Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=415, message=Unsupported Media Type, url=http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/google/upload}
```

I have tried multiple tutorials but it's a tough problem to solve. What am I doing wrong in my C# code?

**Edit:**
I have minimized my problem, to the following:

```
[HttpPost("upload")]
public IActionResult Upload([FromForm] IFormFile file)
{

     Console.WriteLine("TESTT " + file.Name);
     return Ok();
}
```

This really basic code fails as well. I sent a file using Insomnia, and this is the error I received:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RestService.Controllers.GoogleController.Upload(IFormFile file) in /Users/niel/School/integratieproject4/dotnet/Project/Core/API/Controllers/GoogleController.cs:line 49
```

My C# isn't receiving a file in any way.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial problem; it is an analysis problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you can't solve this problem by looking at tutorials or copy/pasting code from the Internet.  You have to analyze the code you've just written.

Comment: I guess the problem is that `IFormFile` has the wrong property-names to work with what Retrofit provides?

Comment: I got it. Parameter-name just had to match...

Answer (score 0):

You should arrange the format type. Change the format from Text to JSON. It will work.